# Java printing 0 to empty cells in JTable

Tags: java, printing, jtable, cell

In Java `JTable` I am writing this code for print 0 to empty cell :

```
for (int i8 = 0; i8 < tgelir.getRowCount(); i8++) {
    if (dtmgelir.getValueAt(i8, 1) == null) {
        dtmgelir.setValueAt(0, i8, 1);
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

`tgelir` is a `JTable`, `dtmgelir` is a `DefaultTableModel`.

When I write a number to cell, other cells turn to 0. But when I delete 0 in a cell and write a number, the number I wrote earlier turns into 0.

Comment: How often do you call this part of the code? Only once?

Comment: Give us some more code ;) My guess is that writing the number in the cell doesn't update the JTable and for some reason it still reads the value as 'null' and sets it to 0. It shouldn't matter how many times you call this code since the value shouldn't be null anymore after the first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use two loops, to loop throw all your cells, row by row like this :

```
//get rows and columns of your JTable
int nRow = yourtable.getRowCount(), nCol = yourtable.getColumnCount();

//Loop row by row
for (int i = 0; i < nRow; i++) {
    //each row loop its columns 
    for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++) {
        //check if your value is not empty or null then change to 0
        if (yourtable.getValueAt(i, j).equals("") || yourtable.getValueAt(i, j) == null) {
            yourtable.setValueAt(0, i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you.